# Comparing dates by vectorization between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this DataFrame with weekly timespans `df1`:

```
      Startdate             Enddate
0 2012-06-11 2012-06-17 23:59:59
1 2012-06-18 2012-06-24 23:59:59
2 2012-06-25 2012-07-01 23:59:59
3 2012-07-02 2012-07-08 23:59:59
4 2012-07-09 2012-07-15 23:59:59
```

i want to find out which dates in my  other dataframe `df2` are between this start end enddates from `df1`. After that I want to add a new column to df2, where the `index` from the matching row in `df1` is in.

My `df2` looks like:

```
           FAID            VALID_TO          VALID_FROM
0  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45
1  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45
2  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45
3  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45
4  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45
```

So probably it's better to summarize my problem shortly:
if `df2['VALID_FROM']` older than `df1[startdate]` but also younger than `df1[enddate]`, then write in a new column the `df1[index]` (index = week number)

```
df2.loc[:,'NewColumn'] = df2.loc[:,'NewColumn'].mask(((df1.loc[:,'Startdate'] < df2.loc[:,'VALID_FROM']) & (df2.loc[:,'VALID_FROM'] < df1.loc[:,'Enddate'])),df1.loc[:,'index'])
```

But then this error occurs:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any ideas to vectorize that operation?

My expected Ouput would look like:

```
          FAID            VALID_TO          VALID_FROM                 Ind
0  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45 2
1  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45 7
2  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45 3
3  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45 14
4  41279041 2100-06-10 02:00:00 2010-03-05 10:02:45 25
```

**SOLVED**

```
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['VALID_FROM']) - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')
df3 = df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="W-MON")])["Date","FAID"].count()
```

Comment: can you add the expected output

Comment: cross-merge and filter.

Comment: sorry, I'm still quite new, what do you mean by cross-merge?

Answer (score 0):

```
    df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['VALID_FROM']) - pd.to_timedelta(7, unit='d')
df3 = df2.groupby([pd.Grouper(key="Date", freq="W-MON")])["Date","FAID"].count()
```

this solved my problem

Comment: how does this involve `df1`? Was `df1` needed at all? If not, then your question needs to be rephrased, as it doesn't seem to describe what you are really after.

Comment: at least no. This was from my first attempt. Groupby did all the job in the end. SO df1 wasn't needed anymore

Comment: In that case, I suggest reformulating your question. At the moment, it is totally confusing.